# Android: How to make the soft keyboard appear over a view when the adjustResize property is enabled

Tags: android, layout

Currently, I'm trying to develop a screen where there are two views in a linear layout in a vertical orientation. The top view is a relative layout containing edit text view along with other views. When the keyboard is opened to type in the edit text, the expected behaviour is the keyboard should be drawn on top of the bottom view, but it should resize the top view.

But currently when I try to do this having set **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"**, the bottom view is also being resized and pushed on top of the keyboard.

How can I achieve the intended behaviour